# Implementing a generic class defined as an interface

Tags: java, android, generics

I'm trying to do the following:

```
public abstract class BaseActivity<S extends BaseDrawer> extends AppCompatActivity implements S{
...
}
```

where BaseDrawer is defined as:

```
public interface BaseDrawer {
    boolean showWait();
    boolean hideWait();
}
```

But gives me the error "Interface expected here" at "implements S". If S extends an interface, means S is also an interface, so there is no reason for this error. Am I right?

Comment: You can't implement from a generic type

Comment: What's exaclty the goal you want to reach using a generic as interface? Isn't clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not right.
There is a reason for this error. 
`S` might not be an interface, but may be a class, which already implemented the interface.
Also event if we assume that `S` is an interface, then who knows which methods have been added to that interface except the ones defined in `BaseDrawer`? Who may know which methods does a child class of `BaseActivity` have to implement once it is not abstract?

Answer (score 0):

The extends in generic definition is different is type hierarchy. In type hierarchy, extends can only used in class extends class, or interface extends interface, but in generic definition, the extends can used to refer a class or an interface, so the S can be both of them.

And you can not use generic type in class definition,.